# Allow Non-Administrator Users to Access Windows 7 Home Premium Via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, non-admin

We know that we can access Windows 7 Home Premium via Remote Desktop [via some workarounds](https://superuser.com/q/680541/45163).

But now, after enabling Remote Desktop, I'd like to allow some users outside of the Administrators group to access the PC with Remote Desktop.

I have tried creating a group with `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add`, but this doesn't seem to do anything toward allowing users in that group to log in with Remote Desktop. I have also attempted some Policy hacking, but to no avail as of yet.

How can I allow these non-Admin users to connect with Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some experimentations I found, that I only need to import to the registry 
these values:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\0000022B]
"C"=hex:2b,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,28,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,d8,00,00,00,7a,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,52,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,20,00,44,00,65,00,73,00,\
6b,00,74,00,6f,00,70,00,20,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,\
00,62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,69,00,73,00,\
20,00,67,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,20,00,67,00,72,\
00,61,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,64,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,65,00,20,00,72,00,69,00,\
67,00,68,00,74,00,20,00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,6c,00,6f,00,67,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,\
00,72,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,6c,00,79,00,00,00



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Remote Desktop Users]
@=hex(22b):
```

That makes RDP connection work, so I can log in to my Win7 Home Premium as a regular user. I think the less we change the registry, the less are the chances that something goes wrong.

I also think, this is the minimal impact we have to make on the registry, as any of the 2 keys are omitted, RDP won't work as non-admin.

And for those who think this hack violates licence agreement: http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows%207_Home%20Premium_English_a0cdb148-2381-47cd-bfc9-9b9102e0cb28.pdf

> f.  Remote Access Technologies. You may remotely access and use the software installed on the licensed computer from another computer to share a session using Remote Assistance or similar technologies. A “session” means the experience of interacting with the software, directly or indirectly, through any combination of input, output and display peripherals.

I may be wrong here, but in my understanding it's definitely allowed to access the machine remotely.

Comment: This worked. I also had to add my non-admin user to the group with `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" [username] /add`.

Also, I had previously created a group with `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add`, and I was unable to login before deleting that local group.

Comment: This approach works with 2 tricks from the [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/680573/256121): 1) run the registry editor with SYSTEM privileges (use `PsExec.exe -s -i regedit.exe` or tweak the permissions); 2) add the users to "Remote Desktop Users", which becomes available after you import the registry fragment.

Comment: tested on Windows 10 home 32 bits in a Atom Z3735F@1.33Ghz with ony 2GB of memory (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914])... works like a charm! THX!!!

Comment: My 2cts are... if you have already a "Remote Desktop Users" group then remove it... only then apply the above fixes... and then check if a new "Remote Desktop Users" group is created... don't forget to add the non-admin user to this group!

Answer (score 7):

I found the registry secrets for this after quite a bit of searching, [in the comments of one of the Remote Desktop articles](http://andrewblock.net/2010/02/23/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-7-home-premium-64-32-bit/#comment-14630), of all places. But, I did have to make some slight modifications.

First, I had to delete that *Remote Desktop Users* group that I had manually created (at the recommendation of [another comment](http://andrewblock.net/2010/02/23/enable-remote-desktop-on-windows-7-home-premium-64-32-bit/#comment-14631)). (I created it with `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add`; delete it with `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /delete`.)

Then, I imported a registry file as the SYSTEM account. I don't know everything this registry script does (I'll update if I gain more understanding as to what exactly it's doing), but it worked for me. Note the changes I made from the data in the source link: I changed the open-quote and close-quote characters to simple double-quote characters and added a slash and additional `0` character to each `Aliases00###` entry (so `...\Aliases0000234` became `...\Aliases\00000234`).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000243]
"C"=hex:43,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,46,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,f8,00,00,00,e2,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,dc,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,41,00,63,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,6e,00,\
74,00,72,00,6f,00,6c,00,20,00,41,00,73,00,73,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,61,00,6e,\
00,63,00,65,00,20,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,00,\
00,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,00,62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,6f,00,66,00,20,00,74,\
00,68,00,69,00,73,00,20,00,67,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,63,00,61,00,\
6e,00,20,00,72,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,6c,00,79,00,20,00,71,00,75,\
00,65,00,72,00,79,00,20,00,61,00,75,00,74,00,68,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,7a,00,\
61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,61,00,74,00,74,00,72,00,69,00,62,00,75,\
00,74,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,20,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,6d,00,\
69,00,73,00,73,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,73,00,20,00,66,00,6f,00,72,00,20,00,72,\
00,65,00,73,00,6f,00,75,00,72,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,\
74,00,68,00,69,00,73,00,20,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,75,00,74,00,65,00,72,\
00,2e,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000227]
"C"=hex:27,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,20,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,d0,00,00,00,d2,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,a4,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,42,00,61,00,63,00,6b,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,\
72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,00,42,00,61,00,63,00,6b,00,75,00,70,00,20,\
00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,63,00,61,00,\
6e,00,20,00,6f,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,72,00,69,00,64,00,65,00,20,00,73,00,65,\
00,63,00,75,00,72,00,69,00,74,00,79,00,20,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,\
69,00,63,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,73,00,20,00,66,00,6f,00,72,00,20,00,74,\
00,68,00,65,00,20,00,73,00,6f,00,6c,00,65,00,20,00,70,00,75,00,72,00,70,00,\
6f,00,73,00,65,00,20,00,6f,00,66,00,20,00,62,00,61,00,63,00,6b,00,69,00,6e,\
00,67,00,20,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,6f,00,72,00,20,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,\
6f,00,72,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,20,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000239]
"C"=hex:39,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,2e,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,e0,00,00,00,76,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,58,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,43,00,72,00,79,00,70,00,74,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,70,00,\
68,00,69,00,63,00,20,00,4f,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,\
00,00,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,00,62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,\
20,00,61,00,75,00,74,00,68,00,6f,00,72,00,69,00,7a,00,65,00,64,00,20,00,74,\
00,6f,00,20,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,66,00,6f,00,72,00,6d,00,20,00,63,00,72,00,\
79,00,70,00,74,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,70,00,68,00,69,00,63,00,20,00,6f,\
00,70,00,65,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,73,00,2e,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000242]
"C"=hex:42,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,2c,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,dc,00,00,00,ae,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,8c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,48,00,79,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,2d,00,56,00,20,00,41,00,64,00,\
6d,00,69,00,6e,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,00,4d,\
00,65,00,6d,00,62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,6f,00,66,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,\
69,00,73,00,20,00,67,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,68,00,61,00,76,00,65,\
00,20,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,6c,00,65,00,74,00,65,00,20,00,61,00,6e,00,\
64,00,20,00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,69,00,63,00,74,00,65,\
00,64,00,20,00,61,00,63,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,20,00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,\
61,00,6c,00,6c,00,20,00,66,00,65,00,61,00,74,00,75,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,20,\
00,6f,00,66,00,20,00,48,00,79,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,2d,00,56,00,2e,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\0000022C]
"C"=hex:2c,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,3e,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,f0,00,00,00,d8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c8,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,4e,00,65,00,74,00,77,00,6f,00,72,00,6b,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,\
6e,00,66,00,69,00,67,00,75,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,4f,\
00,70,00,65,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,73,00,00,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,00,\
62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,69,00,73,00,20,\
00,67,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,63,00,61,00,6e,00,20,00,68,00,61,00,\
76,00,65,00,20,00,73,00,6f,00,6d,00,65,00,20,00,61,00,64,00,6d,00,69,00,6e,\
00,69,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,20,00,70,00,72,00,\
69,00,76,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,67,00,65,00,73,00,20,00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,6d,\
00,61,00,6e,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,20,00,63,00,6f,00,6e,00,66,00,69,00,67,00,\
75,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,00,6f,00,66,00,20,00,6e,00,65,\
00,74,00,77,00,6f,00,72,00,6b,00,69,00,6e,00,67,00,20,00,66,00,65,00,61,00,\
74,00,75,00,72,00,65,00,73,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000223]
"C"=hex:23,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,16,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,c8,00,00,00,bc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,84,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,50,00,6f,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,20,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,\
73,00,00,00,50,00,6f,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,20,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,73,\
00,20,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,20,00,69,00,6e,00,63,00,6c,00,75,00,64,00,65,00,\
64,00,20,00,66,00,6f,00,72,00,20,00,62,00,61,00,63,00,6b,00,77,00,61,00,72,\
00,64,00,73,00,20,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,62,00,69,00,\
6c,00,69,00,74,00,79,00,20,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,20,00,70,00,6f,00,73,00,73,\
00,65,00,73,00,73,00,20,00,6c,00,69,00,6d,00,69,00,74,00,65,00,64,00,20,00,\
61,00,64,00,6d,00,69,00,6e,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,76,\
00,65,00,20,00,70,00,6f,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,73,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\0000022B]
"C"=hex:2b,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,28,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,d8,00,00,00,7a,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,52,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,20,00,44,00,65,00,73,00,\
6b,00,74,00,6f,00,70,00,20,00,55,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,4d,00,65,00,6d,\
00,62,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,20,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,69,00,73,00,\
20,00,67,00,72,00,6f,00,75,00,70,00,20,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,20,00,67,00,72,\
00,61,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,64,00,20,00,74,00,68,00,65,00,20,00,72,00,69,00,\
67,00,68,00,74,00,20,00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,6c,00,6f,00,67,00,6f,00,6e,00,20,\
00,72,00,65,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,6c,00,79,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\00000228]
"C"=hex:28,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00,00,00,14,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,c4,00,00,00,4a,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,02,\
00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,13,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,00,4c,\
00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,0c,00,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
00,18,00,1f,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,01,02,\
00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,\
00,20,02,00,00,52,00,65,00,70,00,6c,00,69,00,63,00,61,00,74,00,6f,00,72,00,\
53,00,75,00,70,00,70,00,6f,00,72,00,74,00,73,00,20,00,66,00,69,00,6c,00,65,\
00,20,00,72,00,65,00,70,00,6c,00,69,00,63,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,\
20,00,69,00,6e,00,20,00,61,00,20,00,64,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,00,\
00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Access Control Assistance Operators]
@=hex(243):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Backup Operators]
@=hex(227):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Cryptographic Operators]
@=hex(239):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Hyper-V Administrators]
@=hex(242):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Network Configuration Operators]
@=hex(22c):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Power Users]
@=hex(223):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Remote Desktop Users]
@=hex(22b):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\Names\Replicator]
@=hex(228):
```

To import the registry file under the SYSTEM account, I used the PsExec.exe tool, from the [Microsoft TechNet "Process Utilities" PsTools package](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). It's a ZIP package, so you don't need to install anything. After unzipping the PsExec.exe file, I ran it as an administrator with the following command: `PsExec.exe -s -i regedit.exe`. From the Registry Editor window, I selected `File > Import`, and navigated the location of the registry file.

To import the registry file successfully, you don't have to use PsExec, but you do need to have permission to write to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Builtin\Aliases\` keys of the Registry, which you can gain by replicating permissions from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM` key to its children (sub-keys).

After importing the registry file, I added users to the *Remote Desktop Users* group (`net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" [username] /add`), and with those users I could then access my Windows 7 Home Premium PC with Remote Desktop.

Comment: This is the most complete answer and it should be the accepted one. It doesn't matter it's yours.

Comment: Worked but my Windows is in Portuguese so I had to change the group name in the registry file net command to "Usuários da área de trabalho remota"