# Is there a way to not show windows user log on screen when admin is remotely connected to system

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I want to connect to my system using RDP connection - I am seeing the windows user log on screen on my tablet / monitor which has options like Ease of access shutdown etc i do not want this to show on the tablet . I would like a screen saver to be displayed or a logo screen to be displayed on the tablet/ monitor as soon as i connect via RDP

I have tried tscon & Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation nothing works for me Also after my RDP session is closed I want to be able to resume my standard user session without me typing password

Comment: You would have to use an alternative which has the ability to disable local I/O input and turn off the display.  The default RDP client does not have that feature.

Comment: Look into a software called NoMachine (NX) that works by taking over local devices and transmitting the screen via video capture, rather than using RDP sessions.  But it won't hide the screen while you are accessing.

Comment: You can also check my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1008656/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-logoff-after-closing-the-connection/1012572#1012572 and see if this method will suffice for your needs. Otherwise are you saying you cannot lock the screen when connected via RDP?

Comment: my machine is logged in as standard user and i want to RDP into it as admin - when i do the monitor/ tablet shows the windows log on screen - i have read the solution of RDP warp but that will not suite my needs . the solution of being able to disable the tablet driver when an RDP connect is established seems the only solution - and re-enable it ones the RDP session is disconnected . Not sure if there is any other solution