# RDP close session

Tags: remote-desktop, vps

It turns out I bought a VPS Windows 10 for gaming stuff. Using RDP I use an autoclicker in a game and works correctly. The problem is that, if I leave RDP, the autoclicker no longer works. The session is closed and the mouse disappears, causing the autoclicker to not work. Is there a solution for not logging out the session when i disconnect the RDP and the autoclicker (with the mouse) is still working? Thank you

Comment: You might want to run the kicker as a service instead. What kicker are you using and which RDP client do you use? Conecerning the logoff, this might be related: https://superuser.com/questions/1008656/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-logoff-after-closing-the-connection

Comment: Hello rudib, sorry i meant autoclicker, this: https://www.opautoclicker.com and RDP client i use the RDP of windows 10, the typic

Comment: I see, do you get looged out or is it just the screen locking? Are the opened programs closed too or is it just the clicker that stop working (but is still open)? In other words, if you connect again, what do you see? Probably a locked screen first and then: the same you had open before?

Comment: Hi again, rudib.  Is the screen locking. Yes, the programs still are open, the clicker stopped but is still open. Yep, if i connect again i see the same programs opened and the autoclick still working. Just stops work when i disconnect. yes all is the same, i think is the locked screen, how do prevent that? thanks

Comment: As a note, when I re-enter I get the screen that I'm entering the account and that it's loading and when I get in it's all the way in, I don't know if it's either that or the screen locker thing

Comment: Ah, yes so that basically (probably) means that it's clicking on the locked srceen.

Comment: Does that also happen when you reconnect immediately or only after some time. If it's the latter you might just have to disable auto screen lock.

Comment: I play a game that have a system idle basically if i stay idle for 20 min kicks me, so if i stay in the rdp the game dont kick me but if i stay disconnect in rdp for 20 min the game kicks me because the autoclick stops so i think is the auto screen lock, how can i do that?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the automatic screen lock. Try `control panel->energy options->edit->turn off screen & save energy ->  never`.

Comment: Ok i will do that, just for in case this shows me when i re-enter the RDP: https://prnt.sc/vl14pm - i will reply later if the save screen works or not

Comment: Update: Now works! Thank you very much, rudib. :)

Comment: Glad it works! No problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not caused by the RDP logout, but after a certain time the sceen is locked automatically by Windows (possibly as a consquence of the screen turning off or the machine even going to sleep - you wouldn't want that on a system that is supposed to run continously). You can disable that in the energy options. The settings should go as follows:

```
control panel -> energy options -> edit -> turn off screen & save energy ->  never
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but, i am using a RDP inside a RDP, and the second machine has autoclicker. You can disconnect from first one, but the second one will never disconnect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).